# batch file from task scheduler win10, not working as excpected

Tags: batch-file

I have an old exe I wrote that I think would make a nice screen saver. The problem is it needs the enter key pressed to start it.

I wrote a simple batch file to accomplish this:

```
start cells.exe 
timeout /t 1
nircmd sendkey enter press
```

this works great when I run it from windows explorer... but when I schedule it to run from the task scheduler on idle, the .exe runs, but the key stroke never makes it through. I have tried running the task at the highest privileges, but still the same behavior. The .exe runs but doesn't receive the key stroke. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Tasks run from Task Scheduler do not have a console from which to retrieve input such as keystrokes. Neither does *start*. If you wrote the executable, why not just modify it to make it an actual screen saver and avoid the issue altogether? It's a matter of responding to certain command line switches that it receives to direct it to take certain actions (preview, run, etc.) and changing the extension and location.

Comment: Yes, I see that when it runs from task scheduler the desktop disappears, I tried a GNU "free" task scheduler and it runs, however it will only be triggered by "on idle" with the premium version == $30    I would love to change the code, unfortunately I lost he code and the .exe about 8 years ago, my nephew found a copy of the .exe and sent it to me, it is around 10,000 lines of code.

Comment: the exe spawned from the .bat using "start" receives the keystroke, but I am using nircmd

Comment: I have even written an app to send the key stroke from VB after a delay. It runs perfectly from the desktop, but it behaves differently from task scheduler. I have compiled the .bat into an exe, same behavior. The only thing I can think of at this point is to write my own task scheduler service... but there must be a simpler way.

Comment: I refer you back to my earlier comment. If you've *written an app to send the keystroke*, why can't you just modify your existing app to properly act as a screensaver? It's an old exe that you wrote - just modify it.

Comment: Like I said in an earlier comment, I have lost the C# code 8 years ago, and it is around 10,000 lines long. So it seems easier to force the exe I have to work.

Comment: unless you can point me to a way that I can modify the exe without the original code.

Comment: Got it. This question is not related to programming (after all, you don't have the code), I'm voting to close it as off topic. Try [su] instead.

Comment: fair enough, is there an appropriate section for this? I am really just trying to understand why a .bat/exe that runs from the desktop wont run from task scheduler.

Comment: Just saw the super user suggestion, I will try there, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Task scheduler is awkward about running batch files you need to put in an intermediary vbs file and run that from Task scheduler instead.
{Assuming your batch file is called *StartCells.bat*}

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "[FullPath]\StartCells.bat" & Chr(34), 2
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

This runs your batch file in a minimised window that nevertheless keeps the focus so that the intended operation of the nircmd line is not disrupted.

Denis

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by editing the registry to point the the .exe I complied from the .bat for my screen saver. I still don't understand why it wont run from task scheduler, but I understand now the this is the wrong forum for the question. Thanks for looking.